# How i can add data like this in firebase firestore using react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Elements in images array should be downloadUrl of images stored in firebase storage.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a code what have you tried so far then from where your retrieving the image urls

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you have setup firebase and firestore in your project

```
export const addData = (payload) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    try {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      firestore
        .collection("projects")
        .doc()
        .add({
          images:payload.images,
          price: payload.price,
          tags: payload.tags
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};
```

but you must set up your firestore and firebase in you project's index.js file or app.js file.I recommend go through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d-gIPGzmK4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9itfjle0ji1xOZ2cjRGY_WB) for better clarity